# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Eclipse Gradle project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, exception

I'm getting NoClassDefFoundError exception when I run this main class through Eclipse

```
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;

public class A {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        // code
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser
```

I am implementing below dependency in gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1.1'
```

Comment: Is Eclipse indicating a compile error for this source file?

Comment: @nitind no it isn't

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed/set your classpath to your current project? Maybe that's why your program is giving you error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java. Browse this link and find out what's the problem